# Yahoo Integration in Android

Tags: android, yahoo, yahoo-api

I'm planning to integrate Yahoo in my Android Application to get the name and personal details  of a user. How do I integrate Yahoo with android?

I have spent several hours looking for a tutorial/sample android application that integrates Yahoo login using OAuth, but I can't find one.

Comment: @ColinPickard It's giving me an error: `Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {oauth=WWW-Authenticate: OAuth oauth_problem=timestamp_refused&oauth_acceptable_timestamps=1340194003-1340195203}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following code , You need Signpost library  [Signpost Library](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/downloads/list)

```
import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException;
import oauth.signpost.signature.HmacSha1MessageSigner;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.synapse.selfervices.R;

public class YahooScreen extends Activity {
    private static final String REQUEST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL ="https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token";
    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL ="https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_access_token";
    private static final String AUTHORIZE_WEBSITE_URL   ="https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth";
    private static final int PIN_DIALOG = 0;
String CALLBACK_URL = OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND; // this should be the same as the
// SCHEME and HOST values in
// your AndroidManifest.xml file
   String CONSUMER_KEY = "";//
   String CONSUMER_SECRET = "";
   private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer myConsumer;
   private CommonsHttpOAuthProvider myProvider;
   private String requestToken;
   private String accessToken;

  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        callOAuth();
        showDialog(PIN_DIALOG);
        // createPinDialog().show();
}

private void callOAuth() {
        try {
                // retrieve the consumer token and then sign it
                myConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY,
                                CONSUMER_SECRET);

                myConsumer.setMessageSigner(new HmacSha1MessageSigner());

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // retrieve the provider by using the signed consumer token
                myProvider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(
                                REQUEST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL,
                                AUTHORIZE_WEBSITE_URL, client);
                myProvider.setOAuth10a(true);
                String aUrl = myProvider.retrieveRequestToken(myConsumer,
                                CALLBACK_URL);

                requestToken = myConsumer.getToken();
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(aUrl)));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e(ex.getMessage(), ex.toString());
        }
}

// this is the callback function that will run when oauth authenticates
// successfully
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("OnNewIntent...");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OnNewIntent - It works!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // whatever you want to do after authenticating goes here ....
}

AlertDialog createPinDialog() {
        LayoutInflater factory = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.pin, null);
        final EditText pinText = (EditText) textEntryView
                        .findViewById(R.id.pin_text);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Twitter OAuth PIN");
        builder.setView(textEntryView);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        if (pinText != null)
                                gotOAuthPin(pinText.getText().toString());
                        onResume();
                }
        });
        return builder.create();
}

private void gotOAuthPin(String pin) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("yahoo",
                        MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        try {
                myProvider.retrieveAccessToken(myConsumer, pin);
                accessToken = myConsumer.getToken();

        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (accessToken != null && accessToken.length() > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Authorized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
                                "http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/profile?format=json");
                StringEntity body = null;
                /*
                 * try { body = new StringEntity("city=hamburg&label=" +
                 * URLEncoder.encode("Send via Signpost!", "UTF-8")); } catch
                 * (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) { // TODO Auto-generated catch
                 * block e1.printStackTrace(); }
                 * body.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                 * request.setEntity(body);
                 */

                try {
                        myConsumer.sign(request);
                } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("Sending update request to Fire Eagle...");

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                        response = httpClient.execute(request);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "Response: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
                                                + " " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not Authorized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case PIN_DIALOG:
                LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.pin, null);
                final EditText pinText = (EditText) textEntryView
                                .findViewById(R.id.pin_text);
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setTitle("OAuth PIN");
                builder.setView(textEntryView);
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                        int whichButton) {
                                                if (pinText != null)
                                                        gotOAuthPin(pinText.getText().toString());
                                        }
                                });
                return builder.create();
        }

        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}}
```

Comment: can you provide the layout xml? Please.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {oauth=WWW-Authenticate: OAuth oauth_problem=timestamp_refused&oauth_acceptable_timestamps=1340197551-1340198751}`

Comment: Check the Date and Time settings of the device you are testing on.

Comment: I am using code snippet but not working getRequestToken() not working please help me