# How to yahoo integration in Android?

Tags: java, android, yahoo

I'm developing a yahoo login integration in Android App and return into main Activity. I have completed all the steps of yahoo integration.I have spent several days for searching yahoo integration in android but i cant find proper way.When i run this code and proper sign in yahoo email and when i click agree button it comes always call_Back URL. Please can anyone help mi.Here is my code

```
public class RequestTokaenActivity2 extends Activity
{
    private OAuthConsumer consumer;
    private OAuthProvider provider;
    private SharedPreferences yahooPrefs;
    private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer myConsumer;
    private CommonsHttpOAuthProvider myProvider;
    private String requestToken;
    private String accessToken;
    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        try
        {
            consumer=new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(c1.CONSUMER_KEY,c1.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            
            consumer.setMessageSigner(new HmacSha1MessageSigner());
            HttpClient httpCliet=new DefaultHttpClient();
            
            
            provider=new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(c1.REQUEST_URL,c1.ACCESS_URL,c1.AUTHORIZE_URL,httpCliet);
            provider.setOAuth10a(true);
            String strUrl=provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer,c1.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            requestToken=consumer.getToken();
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(strUrl)));
            
        }
        
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e(ex.getMessage(), ex.toString());
            
        }
        
    
        
    }
    
    @Override
    
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        yahooPrefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        final Uri uri=intent.getData();
        
        if(uri!=null && uri.getScheme().equals(c1.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME))
        {
            Log.i(c1.TAG, "Callback received : " + uri);
            Log.i(c1.TAG, "Retrieving Access Token");
            getAccessToken(uri);
        }
        
    }
    
    
    private void getRequestToken()
    {
        try
        {
            String url=provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, c1.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND );
            this.startActivity(i);
            
            
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(c1.TAG, "Error retrieving request token", e1);
        }
    }
    
    private void getAccessToken(Uri uri)
    {
        
        final String oauthVerifier=uri.getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);
        final Editor edit=yahooPrefs.edit();
        edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN,consumer.getToken());
        edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,consumer.getTokenSecret());
        edit.commit();
        
        String token=yahooPrefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
        String secret=yahooPrefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,"");
        
        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);
        this.startActivity(new Intent(this,OAuthMain.class));
        Log.i(c1.TAG, "Access Token Retrieved");
        
    }

}






  public class c1 
    {
        public static final String CONSUMER_KEY     = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET  = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    
        
        public static final String SCOPE            = "http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/";
        
        public static final String REQUEST_URL      = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token";
        
        //https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/
    
        public static final String ACCESS_URL       = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_access_token"; 
        //https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token"
        
        public static final String AUTHORIZE_URL    = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth";
        //https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth"
        //public static final String UNAUTHORIZE_URL  = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke";
            
        public static final String GET_CONTACTS_FROM_YAHOO_REQUEST="http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/{guid}/contacts";
        
        public static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";
        
        public static final String  OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME   = "http";
        public static final String  OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST     = "www.bcod.co.in";
        public static final String  OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL      = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
        public static final String  APP_NAME                = "Demo_Oauth1";
        public static final String  TAG = null;
    
    }
```

Thanks in advanced .

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11119098/1218762

Comment: I already try student badge example but when i run this the application is asking for Oath pin in dialog box.And i don't know which type of Oath pin is asking for authorization for retrieving the contact ?

Comment: see this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23781331/android-how-to-login-with-yahoo/24060638#24060638