# Email authentication (Gmail, Yahoo etc) -- android

Tags: android, gmail, yahoo

I am pretty new to this topic, is that possible to authenticate all email id in one stretch. Actual need is i want to authenticate the email(gmail, yahoo etc) in my application, once the authenticate approves, it should continue to my application. It may be single sign on or whatever. Is this possible to do. Can anyone guide me on this topic. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819142/how-should-i-validate-an-e-mail-address-on-android

Comment: authenticate means whether valid email id(entered proper mail id) or valid email address(working email id or not)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if you mean how to validate if a string is a valid e-mail address or how to authenticate a user using an e-mail address.

If you want to validate if an entered e-mail address is valid, I'd recommend that you use the [Patterns utility class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Patterns.html):

```
String email = "john.doe@gmail.com";
if(Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
    // e-mail is valid
}
else {
    // e-mail is invalid
}
```

If you want to authenticate a user using an e-mail address, I'd really recommend that you take a look at how to authenticate a user using oAuth2 and one of the Google accounts on the device. Google engineer Tim Bray has written a very easy to follow guide on the Google Developer blog about [how to verify back end calls from Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html).

UPDATE: Since you're asking for a way to authenticate a Google or Yahoo account I'll update my answer here:

First of all, I would never ever let a third-party app know the password to my email account. Besides, it would be absolutely crazy to ask for gmail username and password when you are more or less guaranteed to have at least one on an Android device. Check [my previous link](http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) to learn how to login using a Google account without having to ask the user for his password. It seems as though [Yahoo has oAuth support](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-guide.html). And there already seems to be a [few questions regarding how to integrate this on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118749/yahoo-integration-in-android).

Comment: Thanks britzl, is that possible to authenticate all email in one stretch by using any private api's.

Comment: What do you mean by "authenticate all email in one stretch"? What e-mail adresses and where do you get them from?

Comment: i have log in form. in that i have to give email id and pass(gmail or yahoo) inorder to login the app. for that i want to authenticate the email id. is there any api which authenticate all the email id in one stretch.

Comment: No no no, this sounds crazy. Please see my updated answer.