# How get yahoo contacts from my yahoo account

Tags: android, oauth, yahoo, yahoo-api, import-contacts

I have tried to implement yahoo integration with my app, let me say about my requirement. I need to implement a feature like sharing about my app to whom, who already in my yahoo contacts. for this i have tried to integrate yahoo API with my application
I have followed the answer described for the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118749/yahoo-integration-in-android)

so when i run this app i got an exception shown below, can any help me please...?

```
    01-27 06:44:31.146: W/System.err(3505): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: null
01-27 06:44:31.155: W/System.err(3505):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:218)
01-27 06:44:31.166: W/System.err(3505):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:74)
01-27 06:44:31.166: W/System.err(3505):     at com.ileaf.yahoo.MainActivity.callOAuth(MainActivity.java:52)
01-27 06:44:31.166: W/System.err(3505):     at com.ileaf.yahoo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
01-27 06:44:31.175: W/System.err(3505):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-27 06:44:31.175: W/System.err(3505):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-27 06:44:31.185: W/System.err(3505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-27 06:44:31.185: W/System.err(3505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-27 06:44:31.185: W/System.err(3505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-27 06:44:31.195: W/System.err(3505):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-27 06:44:31.195: W/System.err(3505):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 06:44:31.205: W/System.err(3505):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 06:44:31.205: W/System.err(3505):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-27 06:44:31.205: W/System.err(3505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 06:44:31.215: W/System.err(3505):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 06:44:31.215: W/System.err(3505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-27 06:44:31.225: W/System.err(3505):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-27 06:44:31.225: W/System.err(3505):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 06:44:31.225: W/System.err(3505): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-27 06:44:31.235: W/System.err(3505):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
01-27 06:44:31.246: W/System.err(3505):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-27 06:44:31.246: W/System.err(3505):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
01-27 06:44:31.246: W/System.err(3505):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
01-27 06:44:31.255: W/System.err(3505):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
01-27 06:44:31.255: W/System.err(3505):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-27 06:44:31.265: W/System.err(3505):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-27 06:44:31.265: W/System.err(3505):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-27 06:44:31.275: W/System.err(3505):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-27 06:44:31.275: W/System.err(3505):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-27 06:44:31.275: W/System.err(3505):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-27 06:44:31.285: W/System.err(3505):     at oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider.sendRequest(CommonsHttpOAuthProvider.java:64)
01-27 06:44:31.285: W/System.err(3505):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:181)
01-27 06:44:31.285: W/System.err(3505):     ... 17 more
```

Comment: Check the following issue http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/issues/detail?id=71 on oauth-signpost.

Comment: Do you eventually want more than just Yahoo contacts?  You might want to check out CloudSponge.  I work there and I'd be happy to answer your questions about it if you're interested.